# Merging partial moments

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Unlike a vanilla date, a moment does not have any required units that must be passed to its constructor. For instance, this is a perfectly valid way to instantiate a moment, with the unpassed units [defaulting to current date and 00:00 time](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/defaults/):

```
 moment.utc('07:35', 'HH:mm').toISOString();
 > "2013-10-24T07:35:00.000Z" //let's just ignore the timezones for now, ok?
```

So how can partial moments be merged into one? For instance, I could just [`.set()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/set/) first moment's hours to values from the second:

```
var mergee = moment.utc('07:35', 'HH:mm');
moment.utc('2015-01-01').
  set('hours', mergee.get('hours')).
  set('minutes', mergee.get('minutes')).
  toISOString();
> "2015-01-01T07:35:00.000Z" //yay!
```

But what if I don't know in advance the format of the "mergee", or even what units it has parsed?

Comment: The Date constructor does not have any required arguments either, it just does different things depending on how many arguments you give it. ;-)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `don't know ... the format of the "mergee"`. Do you mean the string value passed to *moment.utc*?

Comment: @RobG: you can't create a date with just an hour value though (omitting year, month and date). Your assumption about "mergee" is correct

Comment: If you don't know what's been passed, you can't sensibly proceed. At some point you have to be able to reliably determine what the values represent, e.g. "14:32" might be hh:mm or mm:ss.

Answer (score 0):

While not entirely supported or recommended, something like this will *work*:

```
var m1 = moment.utc('07:35', 'HH:mm');
var m2 = moment.utc('2015-01-01');

var merged = moment.utc(m1._i + ' ' + m2._i, m1._f + ' ' + m2._f);
```

The space separator isn't necessarily required, but it might prevent conflicts with certain formats.

I could see that you might have troubles though if both moments contained the same elements with different data.